# angularjs module dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, breeze

I've defined my main module as such:

```js
angular.module('domiciliations', ['domiciliations.service', 'loggerService', 'person.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/domiciliations/mandats', { templateUrl: 'domiciliations/views/mandats.html', controller: mandatsCtrl }).
      when('/domiciliations/mandats/:rum', { templateUrl: 'domiciliations/views/mandat.html', controller: mandatCtrl }).
      otherwise({ redirectTo: '/domiciliations/mandats' });
  }]).
  value('toastr', window.toastr).
  value('breeze', window.breeze);
```

My problem is how to how specify module dependencies in my controller?

If I do:

```js
angular.module('domiciliations.service', ['ngResource', 'breeze', 'loggerService']).
  factory('Domiciliation', function ($resource, breeze, logger) {
}
```

Then I get an error 'no module: breeze'.

It works if I do:

```js
angular.module('domiciliations.service', ['ngResource']).
   factory('Domiciliation', function ($resource, breeze, logger) {
}
```

So how am I suppose to specify dependencies on breeze and logger?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`breeze` is not a module - it's a [value (shorthand for service)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide#value) in the `domiciliations` module: `value('breeze', window.breeze);`.

When you do:

```js
angular.module('domiciliations.service', ['ngResource', 'breeze', 'loggerService']).
  factory('Domiciliation', function ($resource, breeze, logger) {
}
```

You configure the `domiciliations.service` *module* with dependencies to the modules `ngResource`, `breeze` and `loggerService`. Angular can't find the `breeze` *module* and throws an exception.

Assuming `loggerService` is a module and `logger` is a service in this module, the following should work (`breeze` and `logger` will get injected in the factory function):

```js
angular.module('domiciliations.service', ['ngResource','loggerService']).
   factory('Domiciliation', ['$resource','breeze','logger',
     function ($resource, breeze, logger) {
    }
  ])
```

Comment: ah, right you are ! I was getting confused, thanks for the explanation, it's a clear now.