# How to install date time range picker using bower

Tags: angularjs, bower

I want to include date time range picker from this [link](https://github.com/RGkevin/datetimeRangePicker). I have already installed git gui and node.js.

From the site it says:

- download the files
- Bower
- add "datetimeRangePicker": "latest" to your bower.json file then run
  bower
- install OR run bower install datetimeRangePicker
- include the files in your app
- range-picker.min.js
- range-picker.less OR range-picker.min.css OR range-picker.css
- include the module in angular (i.e. in app.js) -
  rgkevin.datetimeRangePicker

See the gh-pages branch, files bower.json and index.html for a full example.

I am new to this and I have never used bower before. How do I install [datetimeRangerPicker](https://github.com/RGkevin/datetimeRangePicker) so I can use it in angular js. I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Answer (score 3):

After you have added the dependency in your bower.json file, you need to run the following command :

'bower install --save'

After the command is executed, it will download all the dependencies your 'bower_components' folder. You just have to include the 'range-picker.min.js' file in your 'index.html'.
Include the module 'rgkevin.datetimeRangePicker' in your app.js

I think this should work.

Comment: so the path to range-picker.min.js will be `src=approot/bower_components/datetimeRangePicker/range-picker.js` ??

Comment: Right now I have a module like this: `angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {...`

Comment: Yes the path has to be something like 'src= bower_components/datetimeRangePicker/range-picker.js' (not sure if you need to use approot/ as well). Please check if the browser is loading this range-picker.js file and you are not getting any 404 error in browser

Comment: As far as your module is concerned, in your app.js, where you have defined your module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' , define it as follows :
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo',['rgkevin.datetimeRangePicker']);

Comment: Actually I have two line of modules: `angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);`
`angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {...`

Comment: I get error: Uncaught Error: `[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo&p…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A264)`

Comment: Yes I get error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: The src path you are giving is not correct. Please check it properly and then add it in the index.html

Comment: When I remove the app root from the path Its not throwing 404 error but I get injection error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo&p…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A264)`

Comment: Use the following in the first line:
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'rgkevin.datetimeRangePicker']);

Comment: I hope there are no typos :/ It should work otherwise :/ It would have been easier to debug if I can see the errors and your folder structure.

Comment: But I haven't.. sorry :( Dont have admin rights on this office laptop. :/

Comment: You are close though... :)

Comment: Ok I will try and see

Answer (score 1):

OK! at root of your project create 2 files
File 1: 
`'.bowerrc'` => extension name with this content

> `{   "directory": "/lib" }`

File 2 :
`'bower.json'` with this content

> {
>   "name": "Application Name",
>      "version": "1.0.0",
>
> "dependencies": {
>   "angular": "latest",
>     "angular-ui-bootstrap-bower":  "latest",
>   "datetimeRangePicker": 
>   "latest"
>     } 
>   }

After that in you git bash or command invite go to `C:/XXX/YourApplication/`
bower install

Then you done.

Comment: racine? You mean root of project?

Comment: bowerrc is a text file? What should be the extension/format ?

Comment: look   create a empty file and save it with this name " .bowerrc " this is the name and the extension too! dont worry!!

if you have command not found after bower install you need to install nodejs  then install bower

like this -> http://bower.io/#install-bower

Comment: ok installed bower and after executing "bower install" It ran some scripts and in the end it says bower ENORESTARGET  No tag found that was able to satisfy ~1.3.0

Comment: replace dependencies version by latest

Comment: ok after I do all this. How would it replacate/reference in netbeans IDE for me to use datetimePicker in my project?

Comment: U have some example 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031460/angularjs-module-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install Bower. I'm assuming you have `npm` installed because you have node.js already.

The command to install Bower is

`npm install -g bower`.

That will enable the `bower install <package_name>` command globally (ergo the `-g` flag) on your machine.

Next, you'll want to create a `bower.json` file. Bower helps you do this. Type `bower init` from the directory you want the file in and follow the directions to configure the settings for your project. This will automatically create the bower.json file for you.

To install your package, use:

```
bower install --save datetimeRangePicker
```

The `--save` flag tells Bower to add the dependency line automatically to the bower.json file you just created. To tell what the command to install the package is, just look at the package's `bower.json` file on GitHub. You'll see that your particular package is named `datetimeRangePicker`. Note that if you try to install `datetimerangepicker` without the proper caps, it won't work.