# Spring controller returns 415 to requests from AngularJS application

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, rest

I am stuck for sometime with something that seems very trivial but I just can't get it to work.I have an AngularJS controller that calls a backen Spring boot app via rest. I can confirm that if I do the request to the backend via Postman, it works well, it's just that when is done via the html page, it just doesn't work, I get that 415.

```
var survey = angular.module('survey', []);

var surveyDto = {
  age:"",
  sex:"",
  status:"",
  chronic:"",
  keyWorker:""
};

survey.controller('surveyController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.sendAnswers = function(surveyDto) {

        $http(
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/surveys/new',
                    data: angular.toJson(surveyDto),
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }
        );
    };
});
```

In the back end I have a very simple Java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/surveys/new", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<NewSurveyResponse> newSurvey(HttpServletRequest request) {

//...
    }
```

When the webpage uses the controller to send the request, I get a 415(Unsopported media type).

[image]

I don't understand why. Before I tried using my own dto object in the controller to represent the data but also didn't work. I am not sure what is missing. I read somewhere that I can use HttpServletRequest, but also doesn't work. Any idea?

I am using the following versions of Spring and AngularJS
- GoogleApis Angular 1.7.9
- Spring boot 2.2.4

**Update**
During debugging of the dispatcher servlet I can observe that the media type used is correct. See image:
[image]

**update 2**
Trying the code that Marco Behler suggested I get the following error:
[image]

**update 3**
I tried adding import for the error above but i get this
[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `consumes = "application/json"` with `consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`?

Comment: @Titulum I tried, but it makes no difference, I still get 415.

Comment: It could make sense to lower the log level to debug (or even trace) and watch out for some relevant information spring might be giving you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says your Content-Type is '', empty, which leads me to believe you are specifying it wrong in your Angular call.

Try this - or a variant thereof.

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let options = { headers: headers };
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/surveys/new", surveyDto, options);
```

Comment: This does make no difference, I just tried. Tbh is the exact same thing I already had. I think the problem is in the Java side. Look at the servlet dispatcher debug I did. It already shows that the client sending the correct media type.

Comment: 1. Your screen shows exactly the same thing, i.e. you do not send in a content-type.You are sending in an accept header, though. They are not the same.

Comment: 2. The error message in your browser says, you do not send in a content type, i.e. it is "".

Comment: 3. The code is also not the same...maybe because...the way you specify the content-type header is not right? ;)

Comment: Ok I see then the problem is in the angular code but I just don't know how to type it correctly doesn't seem to work. I also tried your approach but no difference

Comment: are you still getting the exact same error after copy & pasting the _exact_ code above?

Comment: sorry you are right, I get a different error, please see my latest update.

Comment: see my updated answer, make sure to import the httpheaders

Comment: I understand that makes sense. But not is telling me that I can't use the import outside the module. Do you know where exactly should I put that import statement, given the code I have? I tried on the first line of the file but didn't work. I just uploaded the latest error message. Could you put in your answer the full code in context please?

Comment: I'm not an Angular developer and I also don't know which Angular version you are on and there's a fair amount of changes between versions. You have to fiddle with that a bit yourself, sorry. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031460/angularjs-module-dependencies